# Proving that $x^n≡a (\text {mod } p)$ for some $x∈\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $y^g≡a (\text {mod } p)$ for some $y∈\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Hi there I am struggling with the following question:

> Suppose that $n∈Z^+$, $a∈Z$ and $p$ is a prime number with $g=\text {gcd}⁡(p-1,n)$. Prove that $x^n≡a (\text {mod } p)$ for some $x∈\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $y^g≡a (\text {mod } p)$ for some $y∈\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that if $p$ is a prime number and $a\not\equiv 0 (\text {mod } p)$, then 
$a^{p-1}\equiv 1  (\text {mod } p)$. But can we use the Fermat-Euler Theorem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then the result is trivially true. So we can assume that $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ (so $\gcd(x,p)=1=\gcd(y,p)$).

Thus $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod{p}$. Since $g=\gcd(p-1,n)$, so there exists integers $s,t$ such that $s(p-1)+t(n)=g$.

This means
$$y^g \equiv y^{s(p-1)+t(n)} \equiv (y^{(p-1)})^s \cdot (y^{t})^n \equiv (y^{t})^n \pmod {p}.$$
If we choose $x=y^t$, then we are done. This argument can be made to work in both directions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I see it now!

Answer (score 0):

If $p\nmid a,$

using  [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html), for primitive root $r,$

$n$ind$_rx\equiv$ind$_ga\pmod{p-1}$

Similarly, $g$ind$_ry\equiv$ind$_ga\pmod{p-1}$

So, we need $n$ind$_rx\equiv$$g$ind$_ry\pmod{p-1}$

Using [Linear Congruence Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence#Theorem), the above equation will be solvable iff  $(n,p-1)$ divides $g$ind$_ry$